# table with foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I don't know why I'm not able to create this table with a foreign key constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS game (
  id     VARCHAR(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
  vendor INT          NOT NULL REFERENCES vendor(id),
  name   CHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
  price  DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Please share the error you are receiving for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible explanations for the error:

- The table or column you are referencing does not exist or is not on the `search_path` (in which case you'd have to qualify it with the schema).
- You don't have the `REFERENCES` permission for the table or the `USAGE` permission for its schema.
- The data type of the referenced column is not `integer`.
- There is no primary key or unique constraint on the referenced column.

The error message will tell you which of these cases applies.